# Creating a function type that returns argument object with possible extra props

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm looking to create a function `flowLens` that takes an array of functions with a special signature / type.

- The function can only have one argument
- The function's arg should be a plain-object
- The function must return all the same keys / value types in the plain-object
- The function can return extra / new properties.

Here was my attempt:

```
type Plain = {[key: string]: any};
type SpecialFunction = <T extends Plain, R extends T & Plain>(props: T) => R;
    
function flowLens (...fns: SpecialFunction[]) {}

const invalidType = (props: { a: number }) => true;
const invalidNotArgs = (props: { a: number }) => ({ ducks: 1 });
const validOne = (props: { a: number }) => ({...props});
const validTwo = (props: { a: number }) => ({ ...props, b: 1 });

flowLens(invalidType)
flowLens(invalidNotArgs)
flowLens(validOne)
flowLens(validTwo)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwJYDsoF4oG8DaBrCEALigGdgAnVAcwF0SEUQBfAbgFgAoUSKAZUgBjJAjgAxAK4pBwJAHs0mADwAVKBAAewCCgAmpWIlQAaKACV1WnfqhqAZIeQoAfAAowFOWFIkVASgxncw5OKDCoLgAzKRl5NEi4OQB3ABkdA1cAOmzIlB9+IRFxGNkFHFoArGYuLkEFcihUADdRJF0VcGhMd09vEiwoBBIUCQBbACMICihmAPQgygkIELq84EaUFrg2gDk5YABBCmoDbo8vfIGhqBGJqZm5oNcB3QlBPHyARgeV+vWttoAeRQXSgPQu-UGwzGk2ms0CYKw2Uy528s1+aygAPaSTkGDBqMuUJuMPu8PmiKgyMJpnGJG+6JqnASyTSeVczVa7U6fiiiVS6Q5my5e0Ox1IvOZ-LZpFc2OBEElLIF7OxKlxkqAA)

Is it possible to do this? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

For types to be validated when calling `flowLens`, you'll need to move the generics to parameterize `SpecialFunction` directly. The following should work:

```
type SpecialFunction<T extends Record<string, any>> = (props: T) => T;

function flowLens<T extends any[]>(...fns: {[K in keyof T]: SpecialFunction<T[K]>}) {}
```

TypeScript allows extraneous properties by default, so you shouldn't need any additional handling to allow those on the return type.